# Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: posts is not defined in Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm newbie in Vuejs. I am try to learning  to code vuejs for couple of hours until I get this error.I  guess the problem is come from props to  to Blade. Here is my code.

// Blade View

```
<div id="app">
    <div :posts="{{ $posts }}"></div>
</div>
```

// Vue Template

```
<table striped hover :items="imageList">
    <template slot="image" slot-scope="data">
        <img :src="'storage/images' + data.item.image" alt="">
    </template>
</table>
```

// Vue JS

```
<script>
    export default { 
        props:['posts'],
        data: function() { 
            return {
                imageList: []
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetch_image_list();
        },
        methods: {
            fetch_image_list() { 
                let items = [];
                if (Array.isArray(posts.data) && posts.data.length) {
                    posts.data.forEach((image,key) => {
                        let currentImage = {
                            'id':post.id,
                            'name':post.name,
                            'image':post.img,
                        }
                        items.push(currentImage)
                    });
                    this.imageList = items;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, please indent your code, it makes it much easier to read.

Comment: Also, assuming {{$posts}} becomes a JSON string, have you tried changing :posts="{{$posts}}" to posts="{{$posts}}" (without the colon)?

Comment: yes,I have tried as you suggest still not working@Shoejep

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this` when accessing your data (if you don't have another scope defined inside). And you're trying to access the properties of undefined object (`post`) in `forEach` loop.

```
methods: {
    fetch_image_list() { 
        let items = [];
        if (Array.isArray(this.posts.data) && this.posts.data.length) {
            this.posts.data.forEach((post, key) => {
                let currentImage = {
                    'id':post.id,
                    'name':post.name,
                    'image':post.img,
                }
                items.push(currentImage)
            });
            this.imageList = items
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is work fine thanks but it is not display here my source index in console show

Comment: it is work fine thanks but it is not display here my source index in console show,<div class="card" :posts="[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;oboss&quot;,&quot;image&quot;:&quot;1583301848.jpeg&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2020-03-04 06:04:08&quot}]"></div>

Comment: Are you trying to pass a PHP variable to Vue component as a prop?